# Short circuit evaluation and side effects

Tags: c

OK, I'm a little embarassed to ask this question, but I just want to be sure...

It is known that C uses short circuit evaluation in boolean expressions:

```
int c = 0;
if (c && func(c)) { /* whatever... */ }
```

In that example `func(c)` is not called because `c` evaluates to `0`. But how about more sophisticated example where side effects of comparison would change the variable being compared next? Like this:

```
int c; /* this is not even initialized... */
if (canInitWithSomeValue(&c) && c == SOMETHING) { /*...*/ }
```

Function `canInitWithSomeValue` returns true and changes value at given pointer in case of success. Is it guaranteed that subsequent comparisons (`c == SOMETHING` in this example) uses value set by `canInitWithSomeValue(&c)`?

No matter how heavy optimizations the compiler uses?

Comment: I think you may be confusing short circuit evaluation and compiler optimisation. In the first example, the compiler will optimise away that entire `if` statement, because it can never run. Short circuit-evaluation would mean that if you had `if(func1() && func2()) { ... }`, and func1() evaluated to false **at runtime** (i.e. not definetely when compiling), then the code should not check `func2()` - the compiler should have crafted the machine code such that if `func1()` is false, `func2()` isn't called.

Comment: That `int c = 0` was there to indicate that `c` is equal to `0` at the time of comparision, I realize that in a case that simple the compiler would optimise the entire `if`.

Comment: Ah, I do apologise. I misread you. My apologies.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Is it guaranteed that subsequent comparisons (c == SOMETHING  in this example) uses value set by canInitWithSomeValue(&c)?

Yes. Because there is a [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point)

> Between evaluation of the left and right operands of the `&&` (logical AND), `||` (logical OR), and comma operators. For example, in the expression `*p++ != 0 && *q++ != 0`, all side effects of the sub-expression *p++ != 0 are completed before any attempt to access q.

---

> A sequence point defines any point in a computer program's execution at which it is guaranteed that all side effects of previous evaluations will have been performed, and no side effects from subsequent evaluations have yet been performed.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Because both `&&` and `||` operator are also something called sequence points. The latter define when the side-effects of a previous operation should be complete and those of the next should not have begun.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluation within the if statement composite condition is strictly left to right.  The only circumstance under which the second test in your if would be optimized out is if the compiler can determine with 100% certainty that the first is identically equal to false.