# please explain the output of this

Tags: c, operators, logical-operators

I was trying c programming and I wrote a small code but I am unable to understand this

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

    int x,y,z,k;
    x=y=z=k=1;

    z=x++||y++&&k++;
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n",x,y,z,k);
}
```

I was expecting output as 2 1 1 2
because the precedence of && is more than ||
but the output is 2 1 1 1
please explain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C uses [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), so when `x++` is evaluated as `true`, the remaining expressions are not evaluated, and no increment occurs.

Comment: but the priority of && is more then || so both (x++||y++) and k++ should be evaluated, i agree y++ will not be done because x++ is true but k++ should be done right?

Comment: Nope. It's enough that `x++` evaluates to `true`. No need to do anything with the right hand part of `||`. This answer is correct.

Comment: @maneeshbhunwal; Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17432858/2455888)

Comment: See also [this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375041/please-explain-an-apparent-conflict-between-precedence-of-and-and-the-actu)