# if 0 is compiled in c program

Tags: c, compilation

I'm trying to removed unused code from my program - I can't delete the code for now, I just want to disable it for a start.

Let's say that I have the following code:

```
if (cond){
  doSomething()
}
```

and `cond` is always false so `doSomething` is never called.

I want to do something like:

```
#define REMOVE_UNUSED_CODE 0
if (cond && REMOVE_UNUSED_CODE){
  doSomething()
}
```

Now this is obvious to us (and hopefully for the compiler) that this code is unused.

Will the compiler remove all this `if` condition or it will leave it and never get in?

P.S.: I can't use `#if 0` for this purpose

Comment: `cond` will get evaluated at runtime - how do you expect it to be known at compile time?

Comment: @al-Acme I guess OP is asking about `REMOVE_UNUSED_CODE`.

Comment: I am not sure about the compiler standards, but compiler should be able to recognize the `REMOVE_UNUSED_CODE` and keep out the dead part, with proper optimization enabled. Not very sure, though.

Comment: Can't you just try it? Also no one can tell you what "the" compiler will do if you don't even tell use which compiler (and which optimization level) you're asking about. I'd be pretty confident that most compilers with optimizations enabled will be able to figure out that `x && false == false` - assuming that `cond` can be easily determined to have no side-effects.

Comment: The fact that this is apparently for a safety-critical system (mentioned below) is kinda important, and should be in the question - safe/reliable code isn't usually allowed to be optimized in the same ways as "regular" code, as higher-end compiler optimizations can *sometimes* introduce different logic from what was originally written (I don't think it changes the actual answer to this specific question - this is a very basic optimization, first-tier - but it's a very important thing to be aware of in general).

Comment: @Leushenko Compiler optimizations can only affect behavior if the code relies on undefined behavior, which safety-critical code should never ever do (in fact no code should).

Comment: I would rather write `if (REMOVE_UNUSED_CODE && cond)` because boolean operators in C are always evaluated in short-circuit, and this way you avoid the possible `cond` side effects.

Comment: @sepp2k that depends on the compiler, e.g. [`-ffast-math`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420665/what-does-gccs-ffast-math-actually-do) breaks the standard. Undefined behaviour is a concept from the abstract language; optimizations exist entirely in the realm of implementation "extensions" by definition, so one should always check to see what transformations are documented. On a different level, unoptimized code provides less surface for possible compiler bugs to affect anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC will explicitly remove conditional blocks that have a constant expression controlling them, and [the GNU coding standards explicitly recommend that you take advantage of this](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Conditional-Compilation.html), instead of using cruder methods such as relying on the preprocessor. Although using preprocessor `#if` may seem more efficient because it removes code at an earlier stage, in practice modern optimizers work best when you give them as much information as possible (and of course it makes your program cleaner and more consistent if you can avoid adding a phase-separation dependency at a point where it isn't necessary).

Decisions like this are very, *very* easy for a modern compiler to make - even the very simplistic [TCC](http://bellard.org/tcc/tcc-doc.html#SEC35) will perform some amount of dead-code elimination; powerful systems like [LLVM](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#dce-dead-code-elimination) and GCC will spot this, and also much more complex cases that you, as a human reader, might miss (by tracing the lifetime and modification of variables beyond simply looking at single points).

This is in addition to other advantages of full compilation, like the fact that your code within the `if` will be checked for errors (whereas `#if` is more useful for removing code that *would be* erroneous on your current system, like references to nonexistent platform functions).

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
#ifndef REMOVE_UNUSED_CODE
if (cond) {
   doSomething();
}
#endif
```

Instead. 
Don't forget to do a

```
#define REMOVE_UNUSED_CODE
```

somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the implementation of the compiler. You should never depend on this.

Instead be explicit:

```
#define REMOVE_UNUSED_CODE 0
if (cond && REMOVE_UNUSED_CODE){
#ifndef REMOVE_UNUSED_CODE  
   doSomething()
#endif
}
```

Comment: I don't see how it would depend on the compiler. It would have to be a pretty daft compiler not to optimize away the unused code. I don't think such bad compilers exist on the market.

Comment: I agree, I would assume the same. However to know for absolute sure, its safer to be explicit. If the result was going to be life or death, you wouldn't make that assumption.

Comment: If the result was going to be life or death (safety-critical applications), there are numerous standards for such systems that explicitly ban constructs like this. In safety-critical systems you are not allowed to have any code which is never executed.

Comment: that's the case here.. this is a safety-critical system, and i'm doing a coverage test to remove all unexecuted code. first step if to disable all this code and later re-run major tests to see that no performance issues found

Comment: If you want to know for sure, just look at the object code. Use the switch that comments the assembly with the c code.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this snippet of your code

```
#define REMOVE_UNUSED_CODE 0

if(cond && REMOVE_UNUSED_CODE)
{
    doSomething();
}
```

`REMOVE_UNUSED_CODE` is replaced with `0` by preprocessor before compilation. 
So `if(cond && 0)` will always be evaluated as false and will never be executed. So you can say, irrespective of what `cond` is, it will always be false.

So I'd rather prefer it doing this way:

```
//#define REMOVE_UNUSED_CODE 0

#ifdef REMOVE_UNUSED_CODE
    if(cond)
    {
        doSomething();
    }
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do it that way:

Suppose you have a function `bool f(void* input)` with side effects.

Then with

```
if( f(pointer) && false ) { ... }
```

the body is not evaluated, but `f` should be.

In the case of

```
if( false && f(pointer) ) { ... }
```

f is not evaluated because of the short-cut rule of the `&&`operator.

If you use

```
#define REMOVE_UNUSED_CODE
#ifndef REMOVE_UNUSED_CODE
if( f(pointer) && false ) { }

#endif
```

the whole code is not even compiled in and will never be executed.

Comment: Shortcut evaluation is only in c++ and not c

Comment: @PhilWilliams, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635722/short-circuit-evaluation-and-side-effects) and wikipedia (citing the standard) says otherwise.

Comment: Sorry. You are correct. Not sure where i got that thinking from?

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but may be helpful. There are compiler-specific intrinsics to do code removal.

For MSVC, it is [`__assume(0)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b3fsfxw(VS.80).aspx)

For GCC/Clang, it is [`__builtin_unreachable()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html).

Notice, however, that if you write something like:

```
if (cond){
  __builtin_unreachable();
  doSomething()
}
```

Your condition should never evaluate to `true`, otherwise behavior is undefined.
Combining both `&& REMOVE_UNUSED_CODE` and `__builtin_unreachable()` ensures that your code will be removed by the compiler.