# C: printf not executed, possible compiler optimization?

Tags: c, printf, compiler-optimization

I have the following line in my code:

```
1 || printf("A");
```

I was surprised to see that *A* is not printed; I am guessing this is due to compiler optimizations: *1* was evaluated as *true*, and, because the entire *OR* expression must have been *true*, the `printf("A")` wasn't even evaluated... Can someone confirm this? Would the program behave like this with different compilers?

Comment: How about `printf("A\n")`?

Comment: See [Short circuit evaluation and side effects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635722/short-circuit-evaluation-and-side-effects). This is not just an optimization; it is *required* behavior. I would suggest that you find a better C programming book. This is a pretty fundamental concept.

Comment: NEVER use `1 || (insert anything here)` because `1 ||` equals expression is true and any smart compiler wouldn't process the rest of the expression.

Comment: "*I have the following line in my code*" Why? :-S

Comment: @alk Well not really *my* code. I'd never write that, it's from a piece of "demo" code which isn't supposed to do anything useful. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the expression `a || b`, `b` is only evaluated when `a` is false (similarly in `a && b`, `b` is only evaluated if `a` is `true`). This is known as short-circuiting and it's not an optimization, it's behavior mandated by the standard. If the compiler did anything else, it'd not be a valid implementation.

This allows you to do things like `a != NULL && a->isValid()` and be sure that you're not dereferencing a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> I am guessing this is due to compiler optimizations: 1 was evaluated as true, and, because the entire OR expression must have been true, the printf("A") wasn't even evaluated..

The decision to execute the `printf("A")` function or not is not made during compilation but it is made during execution of the program. So, this rule out your explanation of `compilation optimization`.

In the expression `exp1 || exp2`, exp1 is evaluated first. If it evaluates to `true`, then `exp2` is not evaluated as result of logical operator is `true` in-spite of the value of `exp2`. However, if `exp1` is false, then `exp2` will be evaluated. This behavior is mandated by the standard.

So, in the expression `1 || printf("A")`, there is no need to evaluate `printf("A")` as the result of the expression will be `true` in-spite of the evaluation of `printf("A")` due to the first expression which is `1`.

Similarly, expressions are evaluated(`from left to right`) when logical AND operator `&&` is used in between two expressions.

Comment: When the LHS of the `||` operator can be evaluated at compile time, as in the question, the decision does not need to be made at run-time.  In the example in the question, even with minimal optimization, the compiler will simply drop the `printf()` from the code; it cannot be executed.