# Why variable y is 0, is not 2?

Tags: c

```
int x=0, y=0, z=0;
z = (x==1) && (y=2);
printf("%d ", y);
```

I'm wondering the output is 0.
Why the output is not 2?

Comment: Learn about [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: Why do you think it *should* be 2?

Comment: Basic property, RHS is evaluated only if LHS is TRUE,

Comment: `x==1` is 0(False), so what happens after `&&` is not evaluated.

Comment: other dupes: [Short-circuit evaluation on C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848858/short-circuit-evaluation-on-c) / [Short circuit evaluation and side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635722/short-circuit-evaluation-and-side-effects)

Comment: Why so much DV ?

Comment: When `(x==1) && (y=2)` is computed, as `(x==1)` is false, it stops calculation, and `(y=2)` is never called.

Comment: @Stargateur: Multiply-duplicated question showing no effort to solve it, I would guess.

Comment: First of all you are printing the value of y which was initialized as 0. Thus it printed 0. Considering as it was your fault and you wanted to print the value of z. Now in z, x==1 is false as it was 0 and as soon as it got false it stopped evaluating the next sequence of code. This how logical AND behaves unlike logical OR. Finally you got 0 as result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of how C deals with the logical operators:

Since x==1 returns "false", there is no need to check the RHS in order to conclude that the end result of the operator && is false. Hence, RHS is not evaluated and y stays at its previous value.